# Plotting a new image without using the old one in matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, image-compression

I'm new to python and matplotlib.
I have implemented the k means algorithm in order to compress and image to
clusters and then plotting the changed image.
my question is: I was not able to plot the new image without using
the old one as a base, I tried a few things but could not quite get the result I want. and it's bad programming if I pass the old image as argument when I can definitely not use it.
Can someone please help?

I tried to create a new ndarray but it did not work.

Here is my function:

```
def changePic(newPixelList, oldPixel, image_size):
    index = 0
    new_pixels = []
    for pixel in newPixelList:
        oldPixel[index] = pixel.classification
        index+=1
    l = oldPixel.reshape(image_size)
    plt.imshow(l)
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.show()
```

As you can see I don't really use the oldPixel values, just its structure.
now I'll show you the type of oldPixel:

Here is my loadPic method where X.copy is the argument oldPixel:

```
def loadPic():
    """
    Load pic to array
    :return: copy of original X, new lisf of pixels, image size
    """
    # data preperation (loading, normalizing, reshaping)
    path = 'dog.jpeg'
    A = imread(path)
    A = A.astype(float) / 255.
    img_size = A.shape
    X = A.reshape(img_size[0] * img_size[1], img_size[2])
    listOfPixel= []
    for pixel in X:
        listOfPixel.append(Pixel(pixel))

    return X.copy(), listOfPixel,img_size
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def changePic(newPixelList, oldPixel, image_size, picture_num):
    index = 0
    new_pixels = []
    for pixel in newPixelList:
        oldPixel[index] = pixel.classification
        index+=1
    l = oldPixel.reshape(image_size)
    plt.figure(picture_num)
    plt.imshow(l)
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.show()
```

Every plot that you generate should have a different `picture_num` in order to have separate plots.

Comment: Yeah, but my intention was to avoid passing oldPixel as argument as I don't use its
values.

Comment: Have you tried to create first an empty numpy array (using image_size) and then fill it with the new values?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking. How to do that?

Comment: Can you please tell me how?

Comment: You can create a matrix of zeros with newPixel = numpy.zeros(shape=image_size) and then fill it.

Comment: it gives me an error: IndexError: index 128 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 128

Comment: I don't really know which are the sizes of each element. Try to create the zero matrix with the size of newPixelList (at the beginning of the function)  instead of using image_size.